# Cronjobs from centos to Ubuntu, having hard time

Tags: command-line, server, bash, cron

i am swithcing my vps servers from centos to ubuntu. Because of the community (jeej my first question to that community).

I have cronjobs running perfectly on my centos vps like this:

```
01 22 * * * source /home/crawler2/env/bin/activate && cd /home/crawler2/project_spiderrooy && scrapy crawl spiderrooy > /home/crawler2/logs/spiderrooy_log_$(date '+\%Y-\%m-\%d').txt 2>&1
```

Tried that litterly on my ubuntu vps but that didn't work. 
Find a snippet online (on here somewhere that bash and dash work different so tried this:

```
01 22 * * * "$(command -v bash)" 'source /home/crawler1/env/bin/activate && cd /home/crawler1/project_spiderrooy && scrapy crawl spiderrooy > /home/crawler1/online/flask/static/logs/spiderrooy_log_$(date '+\%Y-\%m-\%d').txt 2>&1'
```

also doesn't work, tried it without writing the log and still doesn't work. The commands manually do work.

sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog:

```
Jan 13 12:11:01 crawler2 CRON[2906]: (crawler2) CMD (-v bash)"  'source /home/crawler2/env/bin/activate && cd /home/crawler2/project_spiderahridderkerk && scrapy crawl spiderahridderkerk')
Jan 13 12:11:01 crawler2 CRON[2905]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

With al my variations i never get the log file written, or the command executed, even without the log write of logwrite without the date.

**The question, how do i run this centos cron in ubuntu, with the logwrite date, and how do i stop No MTA installed crap?**

Thanks.

Comment: `source`is a bashism - the POSIX equivalent is `.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to run whatever after `$(command -v  bash)` as a `bash` command (`bash -c ...`), otherwise the whole thing would be treated as file(s) to be interpreted by `bash`.

Do:

```
"$(command -v bash)" -c 'source ...'
```

So, in `crontab`:

```
01 22 * * * "$(command -v bash)" -c 'source ...'
```

Comment: got it working now with https://stackoverflow.com/a/7031758/9108711 , SHELL=/bin/bash above the cronjob, is that a good way to handle this?

Comment: @user9108711 No, it is not. Ubuntu defaults to `sh` (`dash`) for many reasons, including speed. While setting `SHELL` as `bash` wouldn't break anything POSIX but i would recommend keeping things as-is. Also, try the method I've provided, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, working! Great community and thank you for your fast response!

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue is that `source` is a [Bashism](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) - which is a problem in Ubuntu because the default shell for `cron` is `/bin/sh` - and that resolves to the `dash` shell.

The best way to handle that depends on a number of factors IMHO. The fix that you found elsewhere using `command -v bash` to run your command explicitly with the (fully qualified) bash shell is one option (although as noted in [heemayl's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/995482/178692), you missed the `-c` before the command string; based on the syslog entry

```
Jan 13 12:11:01 crawler2 CRON[2906]: (crawler2) CMD (-v bash)"  'source /home/crawler2/env/bin/activate && cd /home/crawler2/project_spiderahridderkerk && scrapy crawl spiderahridderkerk')
```

it actually *looks* more like your crontab entry was

```
01 22 * * * "($command -v bash)" source /home/crawler1/env/bin/activate && cd /home/crawler1/project_spiderrooy && scrapy crawl spiderrooy > /home/crawler1/online/flask/static/logs/spiderrooy_log_$(date '+\%Y-\%m-\%d').txt 2>&1'
```

such that `($command -v bash)` expanded to `( -v bash)` which attempted to execute `-v bash` in a subshell as well, rather than running `command -v bash` inside a command substitution).

In practice, it's unlikely (given cron's rather restricted default argument) that plain `bash` is going to resolve to anything different from `$(command -v bash)`, so IMHO plain `bash -c '. . .'` or `/bin/bash -c '. . .'` would also be acceptable.

In comments, you noted your own solution was to add `SHELL=/bin/bash` - personally I have no problem with that: if you are concerned about the overhead of bash versus dash you can always limit the scope to a particular entry or group of entries e.g.

```
# default shell
*/3 * * * * /bin/echo "Job 1 run with \$SHELL=$SHELL" >> $HOME/crontab.log

SHELL=/bin/bash
*/5 * * * * /bin/echo "Job 2 run with \$SHELL=$SHELL" >> $HOME/crontab.log

SHELL=/bin/sh
*/7 * * * * /bin/echo "Job 3 run with \$SHELL=$SHELL" >> $HOME/crontab.log
```

results in

```
$ tail -f ~/crontab.log
Job 1 run with $SHELL=/bin/sh
Job 3 run with $SHELL=/bin/sh
Job 2 run with $SHELL=/bin/bash
Job 1 run with $SHELL=/bin/sh
Job 1 run with $SHELL=/bin/sh
Job 2 run with $SHELL=/bin/bash
Job 3 run with $SHELL=/bin/sh
```

Finally, if `/home/crawler1/env/bin/activate` is in fact a POSIX script (or can be made so relatively easily) and the remaining commands in your job are either binary executables or scripts with their own valid shebang lines, then you could simply change the `source` command to its POSIX-equivalent `.` such that everything runs in the default `dash` shell.